# Three js Postprocessing

Tags: three.js, post-processing

i'm having a problem to replicate an example inside vue js.(https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing)

when adding DotScreenShader or RGBShiftShader, uniforms is null.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mcnulty-5rk7j?file=/src/App.vue:220-248

What am I doing wrong?

I try import libraries from npm (three-full, three-effectcomposer, importing like this https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing), but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Found several issues, but in this example it's quite clear.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mcnulty-5rk7j?file=/src/App.vue